# Spring configuration - Autowired bean required?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, autowired

I have the situation where a protoype bean contains a singleton bean. In order to achieve it, I had to create 2 configuration classes. Is it possible to merge my 2 confgiuration classes into a single one?

**Singleton class:**

```
public class MySingleton {
}
```

**Prototype class:**

```
public class MyPrototype {

    private MySingleton b;

    public MyPrototype(MySingleton b) {
       this.b = b;
   }
}
```

**Configuration class 1:**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClassA {

   @Bean
   public MySingleton myBean() {
       return new MySingleton();
   }
```

}

**Configuration class 2:**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClassB {

   @Autowired
   public MySingleton mb;

   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   public MyPrototype myPrototype() {
       return new MyPrototype(mb);
   }
```

}

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible.

Comment: Well, I was not saying this isn't possible, was just wondering how this could be better configured. Answer from Tanja below is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass {

   @Bean
   public MySingleton myBean() {
     return new MySingleton();
   } 

   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   public MyPrototype myPrototype(MySingleton myBean) {
     return new MyPrototype(myBean);
   }
}
```

The BeanFactory should search for a bean of type MySingleton when creating the prototype bean and inject it into the method `myPrototype`.